# Can I migrate a content database from 2007 -> 2010 if SP1 has already been applied to SP2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, upgrade

I am working on upgrading a SharePoint Farm from MOSS 2007 to SP2010 enterprise edition. The existing 2007 farm has a webserver running all services, and a db server. The upgraded farm will have the same setup, though on newer hardware (Both are virtual machines.

I have performed the upgrade and worked though all the issues I encountered. My plan is to now schedule a time when I will put the old farm into read only, take a fresh copy of the database and upgrade using the database attach method. After wards I will clone both servers and have identical production/test environments

My question is: If I apply service pack 1, then upgrade my content db using database attach, will it upgrade it to the correct version? Or do I have to start with a plain install, upgrade the content db, then apply SP1? Similiarily, if I tried to add an RTM contentdb to a sharepoint farm running SP1 would it be updated?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your 2007 farm is SP2 or higher, you should have no problem attaching and upgrading those databases to 2010, regardless of the 2010 patch level.  Trying to upgrade a 2007 RTM Content DB to 2010 probably won't end well, however.

That said, the attach/upgrade may work fine but you could have all kinds of other issues depending on the state of the content in your 2007 ContentDB, but that isn't an Upgrade problem per se.